# mathematical representation of a pure sinusoidal tone

Tags: physics, periodic-functions, wave-equation

Considering the case of a pure sinusoidal tone, e.g. the tuning A note at $440 \text{Hz}$, how can one mathematically represent the pressure wave resulting? For the sake of simplicity, I want to ignore any attenuation.

If I use $A(t) = \sin(2 \pi f t)$, $t$ being time and $A$ amplitude, I guess that means how the amplitude (or pressure, in an unspecified unit) varies with time, but such a function can only refer to a single point, can't it?

Given that sound waves propagate in 3D space, how can I represent that in this very simple case of a pure sinusoidal A tone? My understanding is amplitude varies as a sin function with time in every point of space and also between different points, again as a sin function.

So I am looking for a 3D representation, something like $A(x,y,z,t)$, but I am also interested in restricting it to a certain direction and find an $A(x,t)$, which should be easy because of symmetry.

I wonder if using $A(t) = \sin(2 \pi f t)$ — how amplitude varies with time in a single point in space — would be enough to demonstrate what happens when I sum up two pure sounds at different frequencies (obtaining the so called "beats"), but I am still curious about full mathematical representation of this kind of longitudinal waves.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: The actual equation representing the propagation of a $3$-dimensional sound wave depends on the geometry of the problem, e.g. the shape of the generator and the (relative) density of the medium. I'm no expert in this, but you can start having a look at the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) and its references.

Answer (score 1):

The typical representation of a traveling plane sine wave would be something like
$$ f(x,t) = A \sin(\omega t - kx) $$
where $\omega = 2\pi f $ is the *angular frequency* and $k$ is the *wave number*, related to the wavelength $\lambda$ by $\lambda = \frac{2\pi} k$, or to the speed $v$ of the wave by $k = \omega/v$.

Comment: Thanks. is there a particular reason for the minus sign before the _wave number_? Because I thought the same expression but with a plus sign. Of course $x$ can be negative and that changes the sign. But what is the propagation direction with a minus or plus sign?

Comment: @AntonioBonifati: There are various sign conventions in use. With the one here, positive $\omega$ and $k$ lead to a wave moving to the _right_ (that is, towards larger $x$ values). In order for that to work, points with a larger $x$ need to get a _smaller_ argument to the sine (because less of the wave has reached them yet).